# ERROR: Failed to resolve: Toasty Affected Modules: app

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR: Failed to resolve: Toasty
Affected Modules: app

Dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:1.0.+'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.shalskar:PeekAndPop:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3'
    implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bhargavms:DotLoader:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty/issues/113

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: Toasty Affected Modules: app

Add this in your root `build.gradle` section

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

You should use

```
implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

from [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/#GrenderG/Toasty) Toasty version 1.2.5 not found on the server please try to use the updated version

**Prerequisites**

Add this in your root `build.gradle` file (not your module `build.gradle` file):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and Add this to your module's `build.gradle` file (make sure the version matches the [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/#GrenderG/Toasty)):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
}
```